# Pushing changes to a certain branch created with Jira

Tags: git, gitlab, jira, push, pipeline

I cloned a GitLab project in Python that has usually 2 branches: `main` and `develop`. Every time someone adds a new feature, they create a new branch from a ticket in Jira, work on it, and this gets eventually merged to `develop`.

I made some changes in the project, locally on my computer using PyCharm. I created a new branch using Jira, let's call it `ticket-11`, it is momentarily identical to `develop`. I want the changes to appear in `ticket-11`. If I use the drop-down menu in PyCharm and select `Git->Push...`, this branch doesn't appear there. And I got an email saying that pipeline failed (I saw that the same thing appears for other branches with other tickets too).

How can I simply push the changes from command line, to that specific branch?

Comment: `git fetch` to fetch the remote branches.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a branch on Jira (or any other git-tool, like GitHub, GitLab, BitBucket, Azure…) you must first announce your *local* repository that there is a new branch. And you can do this with `git fetch`. This command you must also execute if another team member create a branch and you want this branch locally on your computer.

But you can also create a branch locally with `git checkout -b <branch-name>` on the command line or in PyCharm as described [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/manage-branches.html#create-branch). And after this, you can push this *new* branch to the remote (Jira or whatever). This way, one step can be saved!